Connect Azure static web app to Azure DevOps via terraform script
I am creating a static web app via terraform, but I cannot reproduce the same result as I get when I create it manually via portal azure.
I want to connect my static web app to an azure DevOps project:

From the documentation is not clear how to do:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/static_web_app
Can anyone help me please?
Thank you
EDIT:
That is how I create the static web app:
resource "azurerm_static_web_app" "admin_crm_app" {
  name                         = "${var.env_prefix}-crm-stapp-westeu"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.admin_rg.name
  location                     = azurerm_service_plan.admin_plan.location
  sku_tier                     = "Free"
  sku_size                     = "Free"

  preview_environments_enabled = false

  app_settings = {
    WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE                          = "Europe/Rome"
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT                     = "${var.env}"
   # WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM                  = false

    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY             =  azurerm_application_insights.admin_appi.instrumentation_key
    APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING      =  azurerm_application_insights.admin_appi.connection_string
    ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~3"
  }

  tags = {
    Source = "${var.iac}"
  }
}

Here the template that has been generate when I create the static web app manually on portal azure:

That are properties that have been generate from terraform instead:


Have you tried any code so far? @Simone

@Jahnavi yes, sure... I added the code I am using... It is not much more different from the example in the documentation... I do not what I can use... I have also seen the template generated when I create the static web app manually on portal azure... but I do not understand how I can replicate it on terraform

To replicate it with Devops you are saying? @Simone

@Jahnavi I mean that I want to replicate on Terraform what I did via portal azure. On portal Azure I "connect" the static web app to a repositoy and a branch on DevOps. But I do not understand how to do the same with terraform. The first image I attached on the post is on Portal Azure, not on DevOps

Currently there is no argument available to add repositoryurl or other properties in azurerm_static_web_app.
If you want to use Terraform to perform action then you can use azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment to deploy a static website using ARM template.
This worked for me and I was able to deploy static website with source as AzureDevOps.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm ={
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.104.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    
  }
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "example" {
  name                = "acctesttemplate-01"
resource_group_name = "vshandilya"

  template_content = <<DEPLOY
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "sku": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "skucode": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "repositoryUrl": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "branch": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "repositoryToken": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "appLocation": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "apiLocation": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "appArtifactLocation": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "areStaticSitesDistributedBackendsEnabled": {
        "type": "bool"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/staticSites",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "repositoryUrl": "[parameters('repositoryUrl')]",
                "branch": "[parameters('branch')]",
                "repositoryToken": "[parameters('repositoryToken')]",
                "buildProperties": {
                    "appLocation": "[parameters('appLocation')]",
                    "apiLocation": "[parameters('apiLocation')]",
                    "appArtifactLocation": "[parameters('appArtifactLocation')]"
                },
                "areStaticSitesDistributedBackendsEnabled": "[parameters('areStaticSitesDistributedBackendsEnabled')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
                "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]"
            }
        }
    ]
} 
DEPLOY


  # these key-value pairs are passed into the ARM Template's `parameters` block
  parameters_content = jsonencode({
    "name"= {
        value = "terra-arm"
    },
    "location"= {
        value= "eastus2"
    },
    "sku"= {
        value= "Free"
    },
    "skucode"= {
        value= "Free"
    },
    "repositoryUrl"= {
        value= "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/_git/xxxxxx"
    },
    "branch"= {
        value= "main"
    },
    "repositoryToken"= {
        value= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "appLocation"= {
        value= "/"
    },
    "apiLocation"= {
        value= ""
    },
    "appArtifactLocation"= {
        value= "build"
    },
    "areStaticSitesDistributedBackendsEnabled"= {
        value= false
    }
  })

  deployment_mode = "Incremental"
}

output "staticDevops" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment.example.output_content
}

OUTPUT:




